# Can't install Wine on Ubuntu. Keep getting this error message

Tags: wine

I've tried both through commands and the software center but keep getting this error message.

```
wine1.6: Depends: wine1.6-amd64 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu8.1) but 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu8.1 is to be installed
     Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu8.1) but it is a virtual package
```

I'm also running a live cd version of Ubuntu.